# Plotting a large number of data points

Tags: plotting, import

I would like to know how to plot when I have a large number of points (arround 600) in a specific format:

```
X          Y
1.000E-03 1.251E+01 
1.500E-03 1.201E+01 
2.000E-03 1.144E+01 
2.484E-03 1.088E+01 
2.484E-03 1.088E+01 
2.534E-03 1.082E+01 
2.586E-03 1.076E+01 
2.586E-03 1.076E+01 
3.000E-03 1.027E+01 
3.066E-03 1.019E+01 
3.066E-03 1.019E+01
```

All I need is to draw a line trought those points, but it would be anoying to write points in format `(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ...`. It would be tedious if I had to insert the commas and braces by hand for every pair of points coordinates.

I'm totaly new in *Mathematica* and I would appreciate help.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with Mathematica, if you don't know anything about it? Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: Could you please upload a sample datafile somewhere so people can help your more easily?

Comment: Also, of course you may use a text editor replace functionality to format that thing into a Mathematica list. Have you tried that at least?

Comment: If your data is in a file and in the format you show, you can use the `Import` function to read it in and convert it to a list of points that _Mathematica_ can process.

Comment: I recall a day not so long ago where I felt exactly the same way as this user (w.r.t. adding braces and commas to data). I see no reason to down-vote the question. For those who are used to Excel and SPSS etc. basic importing of data isn't as trivial as it might seem to a seasoned M programmer.

Comment: @AndyRoss But you _still_ can copy-paste 600 points from a text editor ... and BTW I haven't voted

Comment: The downvoting is ([I presume](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274/handling-blatant-rtfm-cases-harmful-to-the-community)) to encourage people to read the documentation first and then post a question once that fails to deliver enlightenment (which can happen...). Here, it's not clear whether the OP has found the documentation yet.

Comment: @cormullion I looked up the [guideline on downvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down), and near the bottom it mentions that it should be used in extreme cases only. This question seems quite innocent to me.

Comment: @jens Indeed, as in this case people downvoted quite soon after the question was posed, not giving the OP much time to communicate or improve it, (had they wanted to). So I can only assume that it was the apparent "no-effort-expended" reason that won out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a complete walkthrough to expand on Zahra's answer a little. I'm assuming that the exact contents of the example in your question is saved in a text (ASCII) file `data.dat` in your home directory (or the current working directory of your notebook).

```
dataContent = Import["data.dat"]

(*
==> {{"X", "Y"}, {0.001, 12.51}, {0.0015, 12.01}, {0.002, 
  11.44}, {0.002484, 10.88}, {0.002484, 10.88}, {0.002534, 
  10.82}, {0.002586, 10.76}, {0.002586, 10.76}, {0.003, 
  10.27}, {0.003066, 10.19}, {0.003066, 10.19}}
*)

dataPoints = Rest[dataContent]

(*
==> {{0.001, 12.51}, {0.0015, 12.01}, {0.002, 11.44}, {0.002484, 
  10.88}, {0.002484, 10.88}, {0.002534, 10.82}, {0.002586, 
  10.76}, {0.002586, 10.76}, {0.003, 10.27}, {0.003066, 
  10.19}, {0.003066, 10.19}}
*)

labels = First[dataContent]

(* ==> {"X", "Y"} *)

ListLinePlot[dataPoints, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> labels]
```

[image: plot]

By the way, if you don't want to see the long list output after the `Import` command, end the line with a semicolon `;` so that no result is returned. Same for the other lines. I just allowed it to print the resulting lists so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 8):

Save your file as e.g. data.dat . Use `Import` to import your data to mathematica, then just plot it. And have a look at this link: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you all for quick answer. You were very helpfull.

(And for those who asks why am I using Mathematica, answer is I see it's much more elegant then other programs (Mathlab or Excel)

Answer (score 5):

Just to note that `ImportString` can be useful here, if the data is on the clipboard rather than saved in a file. Just type

```
data = ImportString["", "Table"];
```

into a notebook and paste the data between the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

For one-off plotting of a moderate amount of data one of my favorite methods is to use Szabolcs's [Paste Tabular Data palette](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/pasting-tabular-data-from-the-web.html).  With this installed you just copy your data to the clipboard then click the **Table** button:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the data is pasted in a format *Mathematica* can use.  I add `// ListLinePlot` to plot:

```
{{0.001`, 12.51`}, {0.0015`, 12.01`}, {0.002`, 11.44`}, {0.002484`, 10.88`}, {0.002484`, 
   10.88`}, {0.002534`, 10.82`}, {0.002586`, 10.76`}, {0.002586`, 10.76`}, {0.003`, 
   10.27`}, {0.003066`, 10.19`}, {0.003066`, 10.19`}} // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]