# How to efficiently process pasted content from PDF

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I had selected a matrix in a PDF file,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and paste it onto my MMA notebook. Below is the exact copy-pasted content:

```
0.9034 "NAN" 0.7163 0.8588
0.3031 0.5827 0.2699 0.8063
0.0418 0.8426 "NAN" 0.8634
"NAN" 0.8913 0.0662 0.8432
```

I want to display this content in the matrix form as shown in the original PDF. Thankfully there was no distortion when the content was transferred; however, the white spaces now became implied multiple signs in MMA.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**My solution**

**1)** Convert content to string by simply wrapping it in `""`

**2)** I then ran into the problem of the `"NAN"`'s becoming apart from the overall string due to its being wrapped by a pair of `""` previously. I couldn't find a quick way to assimilate them back into the larger string but to manually modify them (by adding a pair of  `\`'s such that `"NAN"` became `\"NAN\"`: [ref](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html#29448))

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**3)** Use `StringSplit` twice, first to split the string at each line break `"\n"` to create 4 "lines"/sublists, and then map it the second time to each line at the `","` to create separate elements for each line.

```
StringSplit[#, {" "}] & /@ StringSplit[%, "\n"]
(* {{"0.9034", "\"NAN\"", "0.7163", "0.8588"}, {"0.3031", "0.5827", 
  "0.2699", "0.8063"}, {"0.0418", "0.8426", "\"NAN\"", 
  "0.8634"}, {"\"NAN\"", "0.8913", "0.0662", "0.8432"}} *)
```

**4)** Replace each `"\"NAN\""` with a simple `"NAN"`

```
% /. "\"NAN\"" :> "NAN"
(* {{"0.9034", "NAN", "0.7163", "0.8588"}, {"0.3031", "0.5827", "0.2699",
   "0.8063"}, {"0.0418", "0.8426", "NAN", "0.8634"}, {"NAN", "0.8913",
   "0.0662", "0.8432"}} *)
```

***Sidestep***: I tried to do this step more generally (since the string enclosed by `\"` might be more varied in future cases), by doing this:

```
% /. "\""~~x___~~"\"" :> x
```

This did not work, probably because `ReplaceAll` couldn't handle more complex string replacements (e.g. involving blanks). As a result, I tried `StringReplace`, and it worked as expected:

```
Map[StringReplace[#, "\"" ~~ x___ ~~ "\"" :> x] &, %, {2}]
(* {{"0.9034", "NAN", "0.7163", "0.8588"}, {"0.3031", "0.5827", "0.2699",
   "0.8063"}, {"0.0418", "0.8426", "NAN", "0.8634"}, {"NAN", "0.8913",
   "0.0662", "0.8432"}} *)
```

**One-step summary**

```
Map[StringReplace[#, "\"" ~~ x___ ~~ "\"" :> x] &, 
  StringSplit[#, {" "}] & /@ StringSplit["0.9034 \"NAN\" 0.7163 0.8588
    0.3031 0.5827 0.2699 0.8063
    0.0418 0.8426 \"NAN\" 0.8634
    \"NAN\" 0.8913 0.0662 0.8432", "\n"], {2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**My question is:**

Could anyone help me think of a more elegant/efficient way to get the same result? The greatest bottleneck, I think, is the manual adding of `\`'s, so I'd love to hear how you can do that programmatically.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate.  Some options and/or related: [(8997)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8997),
[(21951)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21951),
[(41280)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41280).  My preferred method is still Szabolcs's Paste Tabular palette.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ImportString` is all you need, as demonstrated below:

[image: Insert copied matrix.]

Comment: I hate you so much >:[ +1

Comment: and BTW my life would have been much easier had I chosen to type in a `"` first before pasting the content from the PDF (in order to prompt MMA to process it).

Comment: @seismatica Haha, yep.

Comment: Nice. I've seen videos on here before. How do you make them?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), I think most do. There are other alternatives discussed [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/how-to-make-animated-screen-captures).

Comment: thnx I'll give it a go!